# Automatic SPARQL Query Generation for DBpedia

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am working on semantic web project where user will input text query like "Name the presidents of US who died under an age of 60 ? " and I have to generate automatic sparql query based on user's inputed text and this will be fired on http://dbpedia.org/snorql using DBpedia endpoint. I am confused how to select subject, predicate and object as we don't know all properties of specific resource.

Comment: Is this a university assignment?

It seems to me more an NLP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) and a Question Answering (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering) problem than a "semantic web" related one.

Do you have any constrains on the question you would like your system to be able to answer? 
What makes you think that a text query is the best way for users to specify what they want/need?

Comment: It is a semester long project. We are making Search engine that will search on DBpedia only and display result back to user. System should be able to answer query if It has data about query only which is basically infobox extract of wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) (general architecture for text engineering).

I suppose you could analyze the natural query, and with Annie and JAPE, you might have a good start to transform your query into sparql.

Hope this helps

Comment: By the way, I was thinking to start a similar project by my own a few weeks ago ^^